# ¿Como podria obtener un QuerySet de todos los Productos que serian eliminados al eliminar un Proveedor?

Tags: python, django, django-models

¿Como podria obtener un QuerySet de todos los Productos que serian eliminados al eliminar un Proveedor?.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Proveedor(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Producto(models.Model):
     proveedor=models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     descripcion=models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria así (la manera simple y facil):

```
>>> proveedor = Proveedor.objects.get(...)
>>> proveedor.producto_set.all()
<QuerySet: [...]> # Instancias relacionadas y que se van a eliminar
>>> proovedor.delete() # Se elimina el proveedor y las instancias relacionadas (productos)
```

Por otra parte si quieres lograr lo que hace Django al eliminar un objeto (la vista `DeleteView` de Django en el admin), que es listar **todos los objetos relacionados y a su ves los objetos relacionados con estos y así sucesivamente**, que se eliminaran también al eliminar dicho objeto. Pues seria así:

```
>>> from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
>>> collector = Collector(using="default")
>>> collector.collect([Proveedor.objects.get(...)])
>>> collector.data
OrderedDict([...])
```

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, pero según leí de esta manera era la mas "segura" y efectiva de obtener **todas** las relaciones, ademas de que es la que usa Django.

Te adjunto un enlace a una pregunta, donde encontraras las otras alternativas de lograrlo:

- [**Get all related Django model objects**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233883/get-all-related-django-model-objects)

Espero haberte ayudado.